# jquery nested selector or .find()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wan to optomize a jquery code snippet. I intened to select a find a child element.I know how to do this by checking the length which can be acheived by two ways.

```
$("#parentElement #childElement").length
```

or

```
$("#parentElement").find("#childElement").length
```

Both of them will return 1 or 0 depeneding when wether the child exist or not.But Can you please suggest which is more optimized,faster & better in terms of coding standard.

Comment: The length is always going to be 1 when you use an id, unless your mark up is wrong.

Comment: This is the poster child of micro-optimization. If your code is slow, the reason is definitely elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

It's ***extremely*** unlikely that this operation is causing a real-world performance problem. But answering the question asked:

By far, the fastest way to do that with jQuery is

```
if ($("#childElement").length)
```

...unless you really want to ignore the `childElement` if it's not inside `parentElement`. That's the only difference between your examples and the above.

Even faster without jQuery:

```
if (document.getElementById("childElement"))
```

not, again, that it's likely to matter at all.

Answer (score -1):

> Can you please suggest which is more optimized,faster & better in terms of coding standard?

Find is faster. You can read more about this here: 
[Learn optimize Jquery](https://learn.jquery.com/performance/optimize-selectors/)

From the documentation:

> The .find() approach is faster because the first selection is handled without going through the Sizzle selector engine – ID-only selections are handled using document.getElementById(), which is extremely fast because it is native to the browser.